# How to save pdf in the local storage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, local-storage

I am using pdf package to generate pdf. I was able to share the pdf but I don't know, how to save the pdf in the local storage.

```
Future<void> sharePdf() async {
final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Container(
          child: pw.Column(
              children: [
                pw.Text('Example', style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
               
              ]
          ),
        );
      }
  ),
);


final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final file = File("${directory?.path}/example.pdf");

final pdfBytes = await pdf.save();
await file.writeAsBytes(pdfBytes.toList());



await Share.shareFiles([(file.path)]);}
```

This is my code to share the pdf. I like to know how to save the pdf in the local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of other answers and [document_file_save_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/document_file_save_plus) package, I was able to save the pdf in local storage. This is the code

```
Future<void> saveFile() async {
final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Container(
          child: pw.Column(
              children: [
                pw.Text('Example', style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
              ]
          ),
        );
      }
  ),
);


final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final file = File("${directory?.path}/example.pdf");


final pdfBytes = await pdf.save();
await file.writeAsBytes(pdfBytes.toList());



DocumentFileSavePlus().saveMultipleFiles(
  dataList: [pdfBytes,],
  fileNameList: ["example.pdf",],
  mimeTypeList: ["example/pdf",],
);}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this package  [doc_file_save](https://pub.dev/packages/document_file_save_plus)

**setp 1 :**
add permission

android ->

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

ios ->

No permission needed. < as package documentation >

```
final file = File("${directory?.path}/example.pdf");
```

**setp 2 :** convert the file to  Uint8List

```
Uint8List data = await file.readAsBytesSync();
```

**setp 3: call this Function :**

Then pass the  Uint8List like this

```
void saveFile(Uint8List data, "my_sample_file.pdf", "appliation/pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing details process download file from url to save in local storage step by step if you already implemented Download just follow the savepdf File only.

**call download function & pass url to the specific method**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
            onTap: () => downloadPDFrmUrl(downloadurl),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 36,
              width: 100,
              child: Text('download Button'),
            ),
      
        
                  );
  }

  void downloadPDFrmUrl(String? _downloadUrl) async {
await downloadPdfWithHttp(
    context: context, url: _downloadUrl!);
```

}

**First download Pdf from http url**

```
  static Future<void> downloadPdfWithHttp({required BuildContext context,
    required String url}) async {
    // print('download file url ==$url');

    File? _file;
    final String _fileName = 'demofilename.pdf';
    final permission = await Permission.storage
        .request()
        .isGranted;
    // print('download exam url ==$r');

    if (!permission) {
      return;
    } else {
      // print('download file storage permission ==$r');
    }
    // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.

    final path = await getDownloadPath();
    //  print('download exam permission ==$path');

    if (path == null) {
      return;
    }


    try {

      // create file name, if exist file then add a incremental value to file name
      _file = File('$path/$_fileName');
      int count = 0;
      while (_file?.existsSync() ?? false) {
        count++;
        // String newFilename = basenameWithoutExtension(fileName)+"($count)."+extension(fileName);
        String newFilename =
            "${basenameWithoutExtension(_fileName)}($count)${extension(
            _fileName)}";
        _file = File('$path/$newFilename');
      }

      var sink = _file?.openWrite();


      if (sink != null) {
        await sink.close();
      }

    } catch (ex) {
    }

  }
```

**Save download file in stoarge by below function**

```
 static Future<String?> getDownloadPath() async {
    String? externalStorageDirPath;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      try {
        externalStorageDirPath = await AndroidPathProvider.downloadsPath;
        // externalStorageDirPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download";

      } catch (e) {
        //  print('permisison error == $e');
        final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        externalStorageDirPath = directory?.path;
        // print('stoarge path == $externalStorageDirPath');
      }
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      externalStorageDirPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    }
    return externalStorageDirPath;
  }
```

Add read / write permissions in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml before  tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If you are still get the Permission Denied error, add the following line on AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
>
```

Don't forget to add libray android pathprovider in **pubspec.yaml**

```
    android_path_provider: ^0.3.0
```